# Why is my background image not displaying?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `style.css.erb` file in my rails app.

I want to display a background image so I added the line with a rails helper method:

```
background: image-url('bnr-01.jpg') no-repeat;
```

The image is not displayed.

I get the error `'Invalid property valid'`

The css that's generated is:

```
background: image-url(bnr-01.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: background css is like this : `background: url('bnr-01.jpg') no-repeat;` or `background-image : url('bnr-01.jpg') `

Comment: url(bnr-01.jpg) no-repeat;

Comment: or at least background-image: url("bnr-01.jpg");

Comment: It is a rails app hence the .erb extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saying it is css.erb file you should use the rails helper as,

Use `<%= asset_path 'bnr-01.jpg' %>` rails helper

**`background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'bnr-01.jpg' %>)`**

You can also use,

**`image_url("bnr-01.jpg")`**

You used `image-url` which is wrong use, `image_url`

[Here is the reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

Comment: You used `image-url` which is wrong use, `image_url` or `asset_path`

Answer (score 0):

as in the comments told, use
`background: url("path/to/picture.jpg") no-repeat;`
The quote-characters around the path are optional.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

To load background image, the following is the code to be added in css,

```
background-image: url("/assets/bnr-01.jpg");
```

this will solve your issue. Hoping that the background image is placed in app/assets/images.